# Building an autocompletion tool like Google's

Tags: autocomplete

All of us have seen Google's autocompletion at work to realize that it is not just a 'prefix' based completion.

For instance, when I write "life universe and everything pdf", it gives suggestions like these :-

- life 'the' universe and everything pdf
- 'douglas adams' life 'the' universe and everything pdf
- 'the answer to' life 'the' universe and everything pdf

I am aware of the general approach of using a Trie or Ternary Search Trees to solve the problem of prefix matching and suggesting autocompletions (some of which have been explained [here](http://dhruvbird.blogspot.in/2010/09/very-fast-approach-to-search.html)), but can anyone throw some light on how Google might be giving suggestions that are not just prefix matches (and not just suffix matches)

If you suggest that they use their huge data of misspellings, etc, then please explain how.